# Can a restaurant bypass Oregon's straw law by also selling boxes of straws?

Tags: oregon

It appears that a restaurant could very easily circumvent [Oregon's plastic straw law (2019 SB90)](https://olis.oregonlegislature.gov/liz/2019R1/Downloads/MeasureDocument/SB90/Enrolled) by selling boxes of disposable plastic straws in addition to selling food and drink (with individual straws).

Section 1(1)(b):

> “Convenience store” means a business that, for compensation, offers or provides a range of commodities that includes food and beverages.

Section 1(2):

> (a) A food and beverage provider or convenience store may not provide a single-use
> plastic straw to a consumer unless the consumer specifically requests the single-use plastic
> straw.
> ...
> (c) The prohibition in paragraph (a) of this subsection does not apply to a convenience
> store that:
> (A) Sells or offers single-use plastic straws for sale in bulk or unconnected with a sale
> or provision of food or a beverage...

By selling straws, food, and drink, I believe they are "for compensation, offer[ing] or provid[ing] a range of commodities that includes food and beverages," and therefore are a "convenience store." They are "[s]ell[ing] or offer[ing] single-use plastic straws for sale in bulk or unconnected with a sale or provision of food or a beverage", so the prohibition does not apply. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than deciding that a restaurant is a convenience store, the restaurant owner can, following the text that you quoted ("unless the consumer specifically requests the single-use plastic straw"), wait for the customer to request a straw, in which case they can give the customer a straw. If a restaurant owner decides to declare that it is a convenience store and not a restaurant, there could be unintended consquences, since (for examples) a convenience store can't serve a glass of beer.